# Revision history does not show formatted code properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting, revision-history

Recently, [I had edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30702717/3) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30702717/3049655). The post looks fine, but [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30702717/revisions) doesn't seem to render code formatting properly. Bug?

Comment: Possibly something is getting confused by the `<!>` thing you inserted after the link. Maybe try replacing that with a proper `<!-- -->` comment?

Comment: You're right. I used `<!-- -->` and it worked! I had thought that `<!>` is a comment. Thanks. Should I take this post down now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the `<!>` creates a somewhat broken document here, and the diff engine choked on that. I've just made a change that handles these cases more gracefully, so from the next build on your diff will look mostly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat) [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296330/revision-history-does-not-show-formatted-code-properly#comment203969_296330), the problem arose because of the `<!>` that I had inserted. I changed it to `<!-- -->` and the problem was gone!.