# Can I start a paragraph with "1."?

Tags: support, markdown

Whenever I start a paragraph with "1." it gets converted into a numbered list.

Can I somehow escape the 1 to make markdown treat it as regular text?

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/317004/how-to-make-clear-that-a-method-can-be-overridden

Comment: OK, But what's wrong with a numbered list there?

Comment: It looks a bit bloated and it doesn't seem to work properly with the code blocks.

Comment: Alright. As for code blocks in lists, leave a blank line and in the next line, indent by eight spaces. See [the last point here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists)

Comment: FWIW, I’d maybe use `1:`, `2:` and so on.

Comment: I think this should be posted at [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @falsarella - Questions about how to format posts shouldn't be on the main site since they're about how to use the site itself.

Comment: The way I found as workaround for this: `&#49;.`

Comment: @BSMP I was just wondering that it is more of a general markdown question than an Stack Overflow specific support :P

Answer (score 155, accepted):

As documented in the [CommonMark Spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/#example-287), you can escape it with a backslash before the period.

```
1\. Example
```

See:

1. Example

Comment: Interesting: it's the only position where this works.

Comment: @RadLexus Looks like it yes.

Comment: Ah, before the period. I tried it before the 1 (seemed the more natural choice) and it didn't work.

Comment: http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/#example-287

Comment: I am making this the accepted answer for the link to the specs.

Comment: Minor caveat: Q&A sites aren't using CommonMark (yet?). This case happens to behave the same way, but others may or may not.

Comment: Ah, the old "cite an utterly irrelevant spec to make the answer seem more credible" tactic. (I understand the citation was edited into the answer by someone other than the answerer.)

Comment: @AdamLear I know that SO does not claim to comply (backwards compat I suppose) But it does 9/10, so it is an useful place for users to look, often more often useful than the meager (?) documentation from SO itself: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help And in a moral plane, it does want to comply, since Jeff was involved in it's creation, and Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe shows on the front page: http://commonmark.org/ ;-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 I'm aware of all of that. ;) We're using CommonMark in Documentation already, and have some vague plans to switch Q&A as well, but we're not there yet, so my comment was just an FYI for anyone who might not know which flavor we fully support.

Answer (score 31):

I don't know of any way to escape it, but you can easily trick the parser:

1. Do you want this?

2.`<!---->` Here's how.

3.`<!>` You can also use invalid HTML.

4.`<z>` There are a number of variations of bad HTML that work.

Comment: I feel like simply escaping the period character is a lot easier. Why would one do it this way instead?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think it's good to know that there's another way. I up voted the other answer, too.

Comment: Knowing there's another way is not nearly as useful as knowing _when_ and _why_ one would _use_ that other way.

Comment: `<!---->` (4 hyphens) would be a valid HTML comment. `<!--->` (3 hyphens) is not, so markdown removes it. Something like `<idontwantlist>` would work too.

Comment: I fixed it, everyone

Comment: @Oriol: Technically, SE's Markdown parser does not consider HTML comments to be valid: it simply strips them out as not being one of the whitelisted HTML tags. The fact that this looks an awful lot like treating them as a comment is fortuitous, but under the covers there's a distinction. [Sometimes, this matters](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277129/dont-show-a-warning-if-an-html-comment-is-being-stripped-from-markdown).

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've never seen that warning here on SO, even when I needed it.

Comment: Just curious: why do you include hyphens?  Just `<!>` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @zondo: `<!>` is not a legal construct in any flavor of HTML, neither HTML5 nor SGML HTML (or SGML, really). Not even XML, which shares the same comment syntax as HTML. If you're used to writing markup the Right Way™, such invalid constructs don't usually spring to mind.

Comment: They're not on the whitelist, so they get removed, I assume.

Comment: @zondo I used to think like that too. But then realized it is invalid ([as BoltClock mentions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321952/can-i-start-a-paragraph-with-1?cb=1#comment338903_321953)) when [I encountered a bug](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296330/3049655)

Comment: Lol, that are some nice tricks!

Answer (score 10):

The original Markdown rules (by the creator of Markdown) address this [directly](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> It’s worth noting that it’s possible to trigger an ordered list by accident, by writing something like this:
>
> ```
> 1986. What a great season.
> ```
>
> In other words, a number-period-space sequence at the beginning of a line. To avoid this, you can backslash-escape the period:
>
> ```
> 1986\. What a great season.
> ```

Why escape the period/dot and not the number? The rules [later state](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash):

> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash
> `   backtick
> *   asterisk
> _   underscore
> {}  curly braces
> []  square brackets
> ()  parentheses
> #   hash mark
> +   plus sign
> -   minus sign (hyphen)
> .   dot
> !   exclamation mark
> ```

Notice that the dot is listed as an escapable character, however, numbers are not on the list. Therefore, you have to escape the period.